# Insert method call into setter causes Invalid IL code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cil, mono.cecil

I mark some properties with a custom attribute. If it is present I want to manipulate their setter to include a method call after setting the value. The called method is implemented in the parent class of the class that hosts the property. The method has one `int` parameter which is actually an array index identified in the manipulation phase.

For completeness the setter (could contain anything) looks like this:

```
IL_0000: newobj System.Void PlayerCspController/<>c__DisplayClass9_0::.ctor()
IL_0005: stloc.0
IL_0006: ldloc.0
IL_0007: ldarg.1
IL_0008: stfld Networking.Data.MoveData PlayerCspController/<>c__DisplayClass9_0::value
IL_000d: nop
IL_000e: ldarg.0
IL_000f: call System.Void Networking.NetworkUtilities::AssertIsOwnerOrServer(Networking.NetworkBehaviour)
IL_0014: nop
IL_0015: ldarg.0
IL_0016: ldfld UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D PlayerCspController::_body
IL_001b: call System.Boolean UnityEngine.Object::op_Implicit(UnityEngine.Object)
IL_0020: brfalse.s IL_0032
IL_0022: ldarg.0
IL_0023: ldfld Starship.Starship PlayerCspController::_starship
IL_0028: call System.Boolean UnityEngine.Object::op_Implicit(UnityEngine.Object)
IL_002d: ldc.i4.0
IL_002e: ceq
IL_0030: br.s IL_0033
IL_0032: ldc.i4.1
IL_0033: stloc.s V_4
IL_0035: ldloc.s V_4
IL_0037: brfalse.s IL_003f
IL_0039: nop
IL_003a: br IL_01a9
IL_003f: ldarg.0
IL_0040: ldfld UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D PlayerCspController::_body
IL_0045: callvirt System.Single UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D::get_mass()
IL_004a: stloc.1
IL_004b: ldarg.0
IL_004c: ldfld System.Single PlayerCspController::linearAcceleration
IL_0051: ldloc.1
IL_0052: mul
IL_0053: ldloc.0
IL_0054: ldfld Networking.Data.MoveData PlayerCspController/<>c__DisplayClass9_0::value
IL_0059: ldfld System.Single Networking.Data.MoveData::Vertical
IL_005e: mul
IL_005f: stloc.2
IL_0060: ldarg.0
IL_0061: ldfld System.Single PlayerCspController::angularAcceleration
IL_0066: ldloc.1
IL_0067: mul
IL_0068: ldloc.0
IL_0069: ldfld Networking.Data.MoveData PlayerCspController/<>c__DisplayClass9_0::value
IL_006e: ldfld System.Single Networking.Data.MoveData::Horizontal
IL_0073: neg
IL_0074: mul
IL_0075: stloc.3
IL_0076: ldloc.2
IL_0077: ldc.r4 0
IL_007c: ceq
IL_007e: ldc.i4.0
IL_007f: ceq
IL_0081: stloc.s V_5
IL_0083: ldloc.s V_5
IL_0085: brfalse.s IL_00ac
IL_0087: nop
IL_0088: ldarg.0
IL_0089: ldfld UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D PlayerCspController::_body
IL_008e: ldarg.0
IL_008f: call UnityEngine.Transform UnityEngine.Component::get_transform()
IL_0094: callvirt UnityEngine.Vector3 UnityEngine.Transform::get_up()
IL_0099: ldloc.2
IL_009a: call UnityEngine.Vector3 UnityEngine.Vector3::op_Multiply(UnityEngine.Vector3,System.Single)
IL_009f: call UnityEngine.Vector2 UnityEngine.Vector2::op_Implicit(UnityEngine.Vector3)
IL_00a4: ldc.i4.0
IL_00a5: callvirt System.Void UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D::AddForce(UnityEngine.Vector2,UnityEngine.ForceMode2D)
IL_00aa: nop
IL_00ab: nop
IL_00ac: ldloc.3
IL_00ad: ldc.r4 0
IL_00b2: ceq
IL_00b4: ldc.i4.0
IL_00b5: ceq
IL_00b7: stloc.s V_6
IL_00b9: ldloc.s V_6
IL_00bb: brfalse.s IL_00cd
IL_00bd: nop
IL_00be: ldarg.0
IL_00bf: ldfld UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D PlayerCspController::_body
IL_00c4: ldloc.3
IL_00c5: ldc.i4.0
IL_00c6: callvirt System.Void UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D::AddTorque(System.Single,UnityEngine.ForceMode2D)
IL_00cb: nop
IL_00cc: nop
IL_00cd: ldarg.0
IL_00ce: ldfld UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D PlayerCspController::_body
IL_00d3: ldarg.0
IL_00d4: ldfld UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D PlayerCspController::_body
IL_00d9: callvirt UnityEngine.Vector2 UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D::get_velocity()
IL_00de: call UnityEngine.Vector3 UnityEngine.Vector2::op_Implicit(UnityEngine.Vector2)
IL_00e3: ldarg.0
IL_00e4: ldfld System.Single PlayerCspController::maxLinearVelocity
IL_00e9: call UnityEngine.Vector3 UnityEngine.Vector3::ClampMagnitude(UnityEngine.Vector3,System.Single)
IL_00ee: call UnityEngine.Vector2 UnityEngine.Vector2::op_Implicit(UnityEngine.Vector3)
IL_00f3: callvirt System.Void UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D::set_velocity(UnityEngine.Vector2)
IL_00f8: nop
IL_00f9: ldarg.0
IL_00fa: ldfld UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D PlayerCspController::_body
IL_00ff: ldarg.0
IL_0100: ldfld UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D PlayerCspController::_body
IL_0105: callvirt System.Single UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D::get_angularVelocity()
IL_010a: ldarg.0
IL_010b: ldfld System.Single PlayerCspController::maxAngularVelocity
IL_0110: neg
IL_0111: ldarg.0
IL_0112: ldfld System.Single PlayerCspController::maxAngularVelocity
IL_0117: call System.Single UnityEngine.Mathf::Clamp(System.Single,System.Single,System.Single)
IL_011c: callvirt System.Void UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D::set_angularVelocity(System.Single)
IL_0121: nop
IL_0122: ldarg.0
IL_0123: ldfld Starship.Starship PlayerCspController::_starship
IL_0128: call System.Boolean UnityEngine.Object::op_Implicit(UnityEngine.Object)
IL_012d: stloc.s V_7
IL_012f: ldloc.s V_7
IL_0131: brfalse.s IL_01a9
IL_0133: nop
IL_0134: ldarg.0
IL_0135: ldfld Starship.Starship PlayerCspController::_starship
IL_013a: callvirt System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Starship.Thruster> Starship.Starship::get_LeftThrusters()
IL_013f: ldloc.0
IL_0140: ldftn System.Void PlayerCspController/<>c__DisplayClass9_0::<set_MoveData>b__0(Starship.Thruster)
IL_0146: newobj System.Void System.Action`1<Starship.Thruster>::.ctor(System.Object,System.IntPtr)
IL_014b: callvirt System.Void System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Starship.Thruster>::ForEach(System.Action`1<!0>)
IL_0150: nop
IL_0151: ldarg.0
IL_0152: ldfld Starship.Starship PlayerCspController::_starship
IL_0157: callvirt System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Starship.Thruster> Starship.Starship::get_RightThrusters()
IL_015c: ldloc.0
IL_015d: ldftn System.Void PlayerCspController/<>c__DisplayClass9_0::<set_MoveData>b__1(Starship.Thruster)
IL_0163: newobj System.Void System.Action`1<Starship.Thruster>::.ctor(System.Object,System.IntPtr)
IL_0168: callvirt System.Void System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Starship.Thruster>::ForEach(System.Action`1<!0>)
IL_016d: nop
IL_016e: ldarg.0
IL_016f: ldfld Starship.Starship PlayerCspController::_starship
IL_0174: callvirt System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Starship.Thruster> Starship.Starship::get_FrontThrusters()
IL_0179: ldloc.0
IL_017a: ldftn System.Void PlayerCspController/<>c__DisplayClass9_0::<set_MoveData>b__2(Starship.Thruster)
IL_0180: newobj System.Void System.Action`1<Starship.Thruster>::.ctor(System.Object,System.IntPtr)
IL_0185: callvirt System.Void System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Starship.Thruster>::ForEach(System.Action`1<!0>)
IL_018a: nop
IL_018b: ldarg.0
IL_018c: ldfld Starship.Starship PlayerCspController::_starship
IL_0191: callvirt System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Starship.Thruster> Starship.Starship::get_BackThrusters()
IL_0196: ldloc.0
IL_0197: ldftn System.Void PlayerCspController/<>c__DisplayClass9_0::<set_MoveData>b__3(Starship.Thruster)
IL_019d: newobj System.Void System.Action`1<Starship.Thruster>::.ctor(System.Object,System.IntPtr)
IL_01a2: callvirt System.Void System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Starship.Thruster>::ForEach(System.Action`1<!0>)
IL_01a7: nop
IL_01a8: nop
IL_01a9: ret
```

My code adds the message call so that the last lines look like this:

```
...
IL_01a2: callvirt System.Void System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Starship.Thruster>::ForEach(System.Action`1<!0>)
IL_01a7: nop
IL_01a8: nop
IL_0000: ldc.i4 0
IL_0000: call System.Void Networking.NetworkBehaviour::LocalNetworkVariableChange(System.Int32)
IL_01a9: ret
```

When I now use the setter in the code I get:

```
InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in PlayerCspController:set_MoveData (Networking.Data.MoveData): IL_01ae: call      0x06000147


(wrapper write-barrier) System.Object.wbarrier_conc(intptr)
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at <b847be55b9fe46ea9a5798e57286b755>:0)
Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at <b847be55b9fe46ea9a5798e57286b755>:0)
System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object value, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] index, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at <b847be55b9fe46ea9a5798e57286b755>:0)
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.SetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object value, System.Object[] index) (at <b847be55b9fe46ea9a5798e57286b755>:0)
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.SetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object value) (at <b847be55b9fe46ea9a5798e57286b755>:0)
Networking.NetworkBehaviour+NetworkVariableDescription+<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<.ctor>b__3 (Networking.NetworkBehaviour nb, System.Object value) (at Assets/Scripts/Networking/NetworkBehaviour.NetworkVariableDescription.cs:36)
Networking.NetworkBehaviour+NetworkVariableHandle.SetValue (Networking.NetworkBehaviour networkBehaviour, System.Object value) (at Assets/Scripts/Networking/NetworkBehaviour.NetworkVariableHandle.cs:23)
Networking.NetworkBehaviour.SetFieldValue (System.UInt16 variableIndex, System.Object value) (at Assets/Scripts/Networking/NetworkBehaviour.cs:119)
Networking.PeerController`1[T]._OnNetworkVariableData (Networking.Data.UpdateNetworkVariablesData data) (at Assets/Scripts/Networking/PeerController.cs:95)
Networking.PeerController`1+<>c__DisplayClass1_0[T].<Awake>b__1 () (at Assets/Scripts/Networking/PeerController.cs:24)
Networking.NetworkActions.HandleEnqueuedActions () (at Assets/Scripts/Networking/NetworkActions.cs:29)
Networking.NetworkController.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/Networking/NetworkController.cs:133)
```

The code I use is this:

```
private static bool ProcessAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly, IAssemblyResolver resolver, out bool modified) {
  modified = false;
  try {
    foreach (TypeDefinition klass in assembly.MainModule.Types) {
      if (klass.IsAbstract) {
        continue;
      }

      if (klass.BaseType != null && klass.BaseType.isOfType(typeof(NetworkBehaviour))) {
        Debug.Log($"Found network behavior '{klass.Name}'");

        for (var index = 0; index < klass.Properties.Count; index++) {
          var property = klass.Properties[index];
          var networkVariable = property.CustomAttributes
            .FirstOrDefault(attribute => attribute.AttributeType.isOfType(typeof(NetworkVariable)));

          if (networkVariable != null) {
            var propertySetMethod = property.SetMethod;
            ILProcessor processor = propertySetMethod.Body.GetILProcessor();
            var lastInstruction = propertySetMethod.Body.Instructions.Last();

            foreach (var bodyInstruction in propertySetMethod.Body.Instructions) {
              Debug.Log(bodyInstruction);
            }

            var onLocalChangeMethod = assembly.MainModule
              .Types.Single(td => td.FullName == typeof(NetworkBehaviour).FullName)
              .Methods.Single(md => md.Name == "LocalNetworkVariableChange")
              .Resolve();

            var newInstructions = new List<Instruction> {
              // Load to the stack the index of network variable
              Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, index),

              // Call the method (I also tried OpCodes.Callvirt instead with no difference)
              Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Call, onLocalChangeMethod)
            };

            foreach (var newInstruction in newInstructions) {
              processor.InsertBefore(lastInstruction, newInstruction);
            }

            modified = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    Debug.LogError($"Exception :{e}");
    return false;
  }
}
```

The method in the super class (Network.NetworkBehaviour) looks like this:

```
private void LocalNetworkVariableChange(int index) {
  Debug.Log($"Local network variable '{_networkVariables[index].Name}' changed");
}
```

**Any idea, what I am doing wrong?**

When this works I want to extend the parameters and also pass the new value as parameter. I could not find out how to do so. Any idea how to do so?

Comment: Modify one property manually first, compile, inspect IL, use that as your template. I suspect you're missing a `ldarg.0`.

Comment: as @Damien_The_Unbeliever said, you are missing loading the target of the call, i.e, the  *this*  (ldarg0)  reference. Damien, please write this as an answer so Sebastian can accept it :)